# How can I draw border line between cell and cell?

Tags: css, web, line, border, tablecell

I want to make line between cell and cell, but IDK how to make it. So I made left line instead of center line. I write this question to improve this design. (cell's left line > line between cell and cell)

```css
#menu li,
#menu li a {
  display: table-cell;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
}

#menu>li {
  border-left: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
}

#menu>li>a {
  display: table-cell;
  outline: inherit;
  outline-color: black;
}

#menu>li.active>a {
  color: white;
  background: #F2B470;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-bar">
  <div id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href='#'>menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>menu 5</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>menu 6</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will you share the html code as well?

Comment: Oh sorry... I thought short code is better, so I del some codes when I write this question..
and I don't know how to put code on comment... so I put edit this question!

Comment: Will do thanks, I have added my answer let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple, is this is what you looking for?

```css
#menu li,
#menu li a {
display: inline-block;
  
}

 li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
border-left: 1px solid black;
}

#menu > li.active > a {
color: white;
background: #F2B470;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-bar">
    <div id="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href='#'>menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>menu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>menu 5</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>menu 6</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I want to draw border between menu and menu!

Comment: I did not get that, could you just right what should be your output ? my code gives you the border between menus

Comment: @KimRuhr I just updated my code, may be you're looking for full border between menus? check now.

Comment: @KimRuhr, did you check the code? is this what you need?

Comment: Sorry I saw it late... umm I want to draw menu center-middle (horizontal-vertical) so I made it by table-cell. umm... like...
               
menu1 | menu2 | menu3 | menu4 | menu5  between cell and cell. I tried your code, but it's make bracking align and make line up and down

Comment: So you want line only in the middle of the menus and not at the bottom?